# How to provide users with isolated drive letters in Windows 2008 R2 (Terminal Server)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008

I need to be able to host several RDP sessions on a Terminal Server, where users of group A see a drive X: mapped to a given folder of the server and another group B see the same drive letter X: mapped to another folder. For instance :

```
User 1, Group A    X: --> C:\data\A
User 2, Group A    X: --> C:\data\A
User 3, Group B    X: --> C:\data\B
User 4, Group C    X: --> C:\data\C
```

Is this possible. If so, how do I configure the virtual drive mapping so that the user has nothing special to do; i.e. I want the letter X: to be available to Remote Apps launched by the user, or if the user logs in to the remote desktop.

Can I somehow use `subst` to get this to work? I would like to avoid, if possible, mounting drive letters on local shares (i.e. I don't like the idea of having to go through `\\localhost\data-A` to reach the user's data).

Comment: If you have ADS, you can set group policies that calls a different logon script for different group. I think `subst` is isolated to different users, so it should work as you wished. If you don't have ADS or if there are too many groups, you may want to write a more complicated batch file that uses the `net` command to find out the group the user belongs to and then `subst` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Policy Preferences to do this with absolutely no scripting. You can base the location on username, security group, client name/IP and a myriad of other options.

Assuming you're on a 2008/2008R2 domain of course.